# Javassist, bytecode manipulation

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I am trying to find the class initializer in a java class file. I can find the method okay, but if main is not found in the class file, then I want it to find the class initializer and inject the code there.

How do I find a class's initializer using Javassist?

Answer (score 5):

The class initializer blocks for a class are compiled into a method named `<clinit>`. The angle brackets are part of the name, so it's inaccessible to Java code, but it's more or less a normal static method.